# What is the branch of mathematics to solve: Given $2X + Y = 21$, $X+ XY = 48$, Find $X - Y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have two equations:
2X + Y = 21 **and** X + X * Y = 48

And I'm asked:
X - Y = ?

Which branch of mathematics do I use to solve this?

Comment: This is a standard exercise in (high-school level?) algebra. You can solve for $X$ and $Y$, then plug those solutions into the expression $X-Y$ to find its value. Or you can try to rewrite $X-Y$ in terms of $2X+Y$ and $2XY$.

Comment: Technically, this is "algebraic geometry", the study of polynomials with $n$ variables and their equations. But this is such a basic algebra problem that I doubt you'd need to delve into actual algebraic geometry to solve it.

Comment: Agree with @user170231 ... This problem is likely from "Algebra II" in US high schools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the system of quadratic equations. Substitute $Y = 21 - 2X $ into $X+XY = 48$ to get

$$X^2-11X+24=0$$

which leads to the solutions $(3, 15)$ and $(8,5)$. Thus, $X-Y= -5,\>10$.

Comment: Where did you get Z from?

Comment: I do not understand. Ah well.

Answer (score 0):

$$2x+y = 21 \quad  (1.)\\ \,\,2xy = 48 \quad\,\,\,\,(2.) $$

Squaring $(1.)$ , we get :

$$4x^2 + y^2 + 4xy = 441$$

Subtracting $8xy$ from both the sides:

$$4x^2 - 4xy +y^2 = 249$$

Using the identity $(a^2 -2ab +b^2) = (a-b)^2$ , we get :

$$\color{#4c0}{2x-y = \pm \sqrt{249}} \quad (3.)$$

---

**First Case :** $$2x-y = \sqrt{249}$$

Adding $(1.)$ and $(3.)$ , we get :

$$4x = \sqrt{249} + 21 \implies x = \frac{21+\sqrt{249}}4$$

Substituting this back gives us $y =  \frac{21-\sqrt{249}}4$

Hence One solution is $\color{#d05}{(x,y) = \left( \frac{21+\sqrt{249}}4 , \frac{21-\sqrt{249}}4  \right)}$

Now $$x-y = \left( \frac{21+\sqrt{249}}4 - \frac{21-\sqrt{249}}4  \right) = \boxed{\frac{\sqrt{249}}2}$$

---

**Second Case :** $$2x-y = -\sqrt{249}$$

Adding $(1.)$ and $(3.)$ , we get :

$$4x = -\sqrt{249} + 21 \implies x = \frac{21-\sqrt{249}}4$$

Substituting this back gives us $y =  \frac{21+\sqrt{249}}4$

Hence other solution is $\color{#35f}{(x,y) = \left( \frac{21-\sqrt{249}}4 , \frac{21+\sqrt{249}}4  \right)}$

Now $$x-y = \left( \frac{21-\sqrt{249}}4 - \frac{21+\sqrt{249}}4  \right) = \boxed{-\frac{\sqrt{249}}2}$$